# Get field names for SQL query from a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, eval

Is it possible to specify field names for a SELECT query from subquery?
For example, I have a following query which returns a pivot table:

```
SELECT [Rank], [a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h]
FROM
(SELECT [File], [Rank], [Piece]
FROM [TableName])
AS [SRC]
PIVOT
(MAX([Piece])
FOR [File]
IN ([a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h]))
AS [PVT]
ORDER BY [Rank] DESC
```

So basically I need these "[a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h]" to be dynamically generated (parameter-dependent), as a result from another query, e.g. from some #TempTable. I guess I need to use some sort of Eval() function (if it exists of course)? I want it to look like this:

```
SELECT [Rank], Eval("SELECT ... FROM ...")
FROM
(SELECT [File], [Rank], [Piece]
FROM [TableName])
AS [SRC]
PIVOT
(MAX([Piece])
FOR [File]
IN ( Eval("SELECT ... FROM ...") ))
AS [PVT]
ORDER BY [Rank] DESC
```

Comment: Read up on dynamic SQL. It's the only way to use variable field names.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I will post the code below!

Comment: Hi Taosique, do not add the answer to the question. Just add it as answer you even may accept it, maybe you will have to wait for a while due to your reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tobberoth, the code in need looks like this:

```
DECLARE @filelist varchar(MAX) =
STUFF(
(SELECT DISTINCT ', [' + [File] + ']'
FROM [#TempTableName]
FOR XML PATH(''))
,1,1,'')

DECLARE @query varchar(MAX) = 
'SELECT [Rank], ' + @filelist + '
FROM
(SELECT [File], [Rank], [Piece]
FROM [TableName])
AS [SRC]
PIVOT
(MAX([Piece])
FOR [File]
IN (' + @filelist + '))
AS [PVT]
ORDER BY [Rank] DESC'

EXECUTE (@query)
```